# Check if value exists, if not add to list

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement, web-scraping

**My goal:** Check if value exists, if the value not exists add at the end of column A. If the value exists skip the ID and check the next value.

**Actual result:** The IDs will be added at the end of line A neverthelesss if the value exists or not. Therfore I get duplicates.

I tried with "if" but I get an error.

**My coding:**

```
Option Explicit


Sub ExposeID()

Dim browser As Object   'Aufnehmen der verwendeten Instanz des Browsers (Internet Explorer)
Dim knotenAst As Object 'Aufnehmen einer HTML Struktur aus dem Browser Dokument
Dim n As Integer
Dim url As String       'Aufnehmen der auszulesenden Adresse

Dim ExposeID As String
Dim letztezeile As Integer
Dim nodeList As Object, i As Long

Set browser = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    browser.Visible = False

For n = 0 To 1
    
    url = "https://www.
    browser.navigate url
    Do Until browser.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

    letztezeile = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set nodeList = browser.document.querySelectorAll(".result-list__listing[data-id]")

For i = 0 To nodeList.Length - 1

    ''' HERE IS THE PROBLEM '''
    If nodeList.Item(i).getAttribute("data-id") <> Cells.Range("A:A") Then
       Cells(letztezeile + i + 1, 1) = nodeList.Item(i).getAttribute("data-id")
       
    Else
    
    End If
    
Next i

Next n

Set nodeList = Nothing
browser.Quit
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Try this: `If IsError(Application.Match(nodeList.Item(i).getAttribute("data-id"), Cells.Range("A:A"), 0)) Then`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have added the coding and tried. Now I don´t got an error. But there are duplicates again.

Comment: Is this maybe happening in two worksheets? I mean you have used `ActiveSheet` on one occasion, but used nothing on two other occasions (`Cells.Range..., Cells(letztezeile ...`).

Comment: I have corrected this point. Everythings happens in the same worksheet. But it will not work.  `Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = Tabelle1
  ws.Name = "IDs"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Values Recognized As Text

You can use the Match function to compare the values like a wrote in the comments:

```
If IsError(Application.Match(nodeList.Item(i).getAttribute("data-id"), Cells.Range("A:A"), 0)) Then
```

The problem is that the data is being recognized as text, and when written to the worksheet it is converted to an integer number. You can convert the text to a number using the `Val` function. Look at the critical line in the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExposeID()

    Dim browser As Object   'Aufnehmen der verwendeten Instanz des Browsers (Internet Explorer)
    Dim knotenAst As Object 'Aufnehmen einer HTML Struktur aus dem Browser Dokument
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim url As String       'Aufnehmen der auszulesenden Adresse

    Dim ExposeID As String
    Dim letztezeile As Integer
    Dim nodeList As Object, i As Long

    Set browser = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
        browser.Visible = False

    For n = 0 To 1

        url = "https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/de/niedersachsen/" _
          & "oldenburg-oldenburg/haus-kaufen?pagenumber=" & n + 1
        browser.navigate url
        Do Until browser.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

        letztezeile = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        Set nodeList = browser.document.querySelectorAll( _
          ".result-list__listing[data-id]")

        For i = 0 To nodeList.Length - 1

            If IsError(Application.Match(Val(nodeList.Item(i) _
              .getAttribute("data-id")), Cells.Range("A:A"), 0)).Value Then
                Cells(letztezeile + i + 1, 1).Value = nodeList.Item(i) _
                  .getAttribute("data-id")
            Else

            End If

        Next i

    Next n

    Set nodeList = Nothing
    browser.Quit

End Sub
```

I think this Internet Explorer version is too slow, so you could ask another question how to solve this with an using xhr (XML HTTP request).

Answer (score 0):

I found a way how it could work. But there is one issue. It skips for every entry which already exists one line.

```
Option Explicit

'Version vom 08.05.2020
' Coding funktioniert, aber Leerzeichen


Sub ExposeID()

Dim browser As Object   'Aufnehmen der verwendeten Instanz des Browsers (Internet Explorer)
Dim knotenAst As Object 'Aufnehmen einer HTML Struktur aus dem Browser Dokument
Dim n As Integer
Dim url As String       'Aufnehmen der auszulesenden Adresse

Dim ExposeID As String
Dim letztezeile As Integer
Dim nodeList As Object, i As Long

Set browser = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    browser.Visible = False

For n = 0 To 1

    url = "https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/de/niedersachsen/oldenburg-oldenburg/haus-kaufen?pagenumber=" & n + 1
    browser.navigate url
    Do Until browser.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

    letztezeile = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set nodeList = browser.document.querySelectorAll(".result-list__listing[data-id]")

For i = 0 To nodeList.Length - 1
Dim x As Integer

Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng As Range
FindString = nodeList.Item(i).getAttribute("data-id")
If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
    With Sheets("IDs").Range("A:A") 'searches all of column A
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then

        Else
          Cells(letztezeile + i + 1, 1) = nodeList.Item(i).getAttribute("data-id")
        End If
    End With
End If

Next i

Next n

Set nodeList = Nothing
browser.Quit

End Sub
```

[image]